# <Permission denied> When accessing Workbook.load("name") in Excel Add-in Excel 2019 Commercial using IE 11

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am trying to develop an extension that runs on a Windows machine and supports a commercial Office 2019 Excel. Excel uses IE11 perpetual browser for this. When trying to load the name using

`workbook.load("name"); await context.sync();`

It gives "The API you are trying to use could not be found. It may be available in a newer version of Excel" . On doing a console.log(), I get  against that property.

Can anybody help on what is the recommended way to fetch workbook name in Excel add-in?

Comment: On further checking through F12, found that somewhere workbook.comments is being invoked within context.sync() which is not supported until 1.10 Excel Api. This could be a probable cause but could not figure out how to not execute it.

Comment: This part of your question is missing some words: "I get against that property". Please reproduce your issue in the Script Lab tool, export a gist, and provide the URL of the gist.

Comment: Script Lab does not work with Office 2019 commercial versions anymore because of IE11 dependency. @RickKirkham - Please provide any alternate steps for this.